# sql database queries taking excessive time

Tags: sql-server

It's been several years since I've worked with SQL and C# .NET so be gentle.

I'm jumping in to assist on a project that a coworker has been building. Something though seems quite out of whack.

I'm trying to provide straight reports on a particular Table in the database. It has 9 columns and approximately 1.6M rows last time I checked.  This is big, but it's hardly large enough to create problems. However, when I run a simple Query using MS SQL Server Management Studio, it takes 11 seconds.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [4.0Analytics].[dbo].[Measurement]
  where VIN = 'JTHBJ46G482271076';
```

I tried creating an index for VIN but it times out. 
"An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch."
"Could not allocate space for object 'X' in dabase 'Your Datase' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full"

It seems however that it should be taking a lot less time in the first place even non-indexed so I'd like to find out what might be wrong there and then move onto the index time-out next. Unless 11 seconds is normal for a simple query when non-indexed?

Comment: 11 seconds is normal - you definitely want an index on VIN.

Comment: The error on the index creation sounds like you're out of disk space - can you confirm?

Comment: 1.6M rows, I'm guessing that this table alone is about 6.5GB. If you're on sql server express, you have to be 2008 r^2 or above which has a limit of 10GB in size. If HDD size is not the issue and neither is the SQL server version, I recommend upping the filegroup initial size by something much more than the autogrowth rate plus the current data file's size.

Comment: COUld "4.0Analytics" be an synonym to another server/instance/dbname ?

Comment: Yes, from the sound of it the database/table are just growing too fast for the space allotted. Going to move it over until the client comes up with a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As David Gugg has mentioned you do not have enough space left in your database.

Check if you have enough space left on the disk where your Primary File is located. If you have enough space on the disk use the following command and then try to create the index

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [4.0Analytics] 
  MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'Primary_File_Name'
              , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
              , FILEGROWTH = 10%
              )
GO


-- This will allow your database to grow automatically if it runs out of space 
-- provided you have space left on the disk 
-- Now try to create the Index and it should let you create it.
```

`SELECT *` is taking too long. Well no wonder how many indexes you put on a table if you are doing a `SELECT *` it will always result in a `Clustered Index Scan` if you have primary key defined on the table otherwise a table scan.

```
Try `Select <Column Names>` --<-- Only the columns you actually need
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's a client's server so we're going to have to get them to upgrade. In the meantime we're going to try moving the data to our server just to see if it'll be more manageable while they find a solution. Thanks for the feedback. I'll be back if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

1. I would not recommend to SET the datafile Autogruth to percentage [%], it is better
   (best practice ) to set it to growth by MB, for example:

   USE [master]
   GO

   ALTER DATABASE [YourDataBaseName] MODIFY 
   FILE ( NAME = N'YouDataBaseFileName', 
           FILEGROWTH = 10240KB ,
           MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
   GO
2. The Error you have got during the index creation were, because that the index didn't have the ability to extend.(because the parameter MAXSIZE is set to LIMIT value).
3. to check it you can do by :
   a. Object Explorer >>> Databases  >>> Right click on the requested Database >>> GO to TAB "File".
   b.T-SQL :

   select 
   FILE_NAME(e.file_id ) as [FileName],
   e.growth,
   e.max_size,
   e.is_percent_growth
   f  rom sys.master_files e
   where OBJECT_NAME(e.database_id) = 'YourDatabaseName'
   GO